# Структура страницы wordpress

Tags: шаблоны, wordpress, вёрстка

В общем, хочу создать шаблон на Wordpress, интересует вопрос по поводу index.php. Существует ли список функций (или я не знаю, как правильно их назвать) для файла index.php? Вот, например, я сверстал [макет](http://jsfiddle.net/no4ts8vn/).

Какой будет код  для файла index.php (шаблона wordpress)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Про разработку шаблонов читать здесь http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Про список функций, используемых на любых страницах шаблона здесь http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference